# $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{a^x+b^x}{2})^{\frac{1}{x}} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

hello i have a question

calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}  (\frac{a^x+b^x}{2})^{\frac{1}{x}} $  where $a,b$ are strictly positive numbers

can you provide me with some hints

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Hint: start by supposing $a>b$ and divide and multiple by $a^x$

Comment: See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details.

Comment: It is $\max(a,b),$ and can be proven using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That's a helluva hint! :-D

Comment: thanks for the hints.

Comment: See also [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969), in particular [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969). Chances are that this has been asked and answered  before.